Where can I read "Survey of inns, taverns and alehouses"?
Where please can I read, online preferred, the: "Survey of inns, taverns and alehouses in England and Wales" made in 1577 (Survey of inns, taverns and alehouses in England and Wales in 1577: National Archives SP 12/115-19)
According to more than one reference, that is the title of the survey. QEI wanted it made apparently because she didn't think there were enough such places for her to take rest. Also, 'apparently' many inns etc made after this were called 'New Inn'; but there were also one or two other reasons for said name all from a similar period.

Is that the exact title of the document?

@PeterEmbling - The structure of this site requires that answers be answers not comments.    Original poster should edit the question to address any issues raised in the comments.

I'm legit not sure if "Where do I find book X that happens to be a history book"? questions are on topic here. Still, this seems a question easier answered by a phone call to your local head librarian. Not casting shade on anyone here. Librarians get 4 year degrees on answering this kind of question, and I'm always surprised how baller they are at it. Even their google-fu completely outclasses mine.

The answer to my question here provides specific location information.

Survey of inns, taverns and alehouses in England and Wales in 1577:
National Archives SP 12/115-19.

If you go through the National archives menu system for collection SP 12, entry 115 you will get to this page, with the following message:

So to read this original document, which has not yet been digitized, you will have to go the the National Archives in Kew.

That's a big help thank you. I had found the same but am trying to save a visit to Kew. The fact that others are coming to the same conclusion leads me to think that maybe this is the only answer. Thanks again.
